# Android Studio - Problem with KOTLIN when building apk

Tags: android, kotlin

I have developed a `React Native` app. It is fine when I test using Visual Basic and expo.

Now I want build mu apk.

I opened my app with `Android Studio 4.2.2`. I have `Kotlin 1.4.31` and `gradle 7.1.1` and configured on my Windows 10 all variables environments. such `JAVA_PATH`, `GRABLE_PATH`, `ANDROID_PATH`.

When I try to build apk, the following message is received :

> KOTLIN : Unresolved reference.

Please, what can I do ?

Comment: did you add correctly kotlin-android-extensions ?

Comment: Thank You. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is important that everthing match up together.

For that change your versions to:

> `Gradle`: 7.1
>
> `Kotlin`: 1.4.20
>
> `Android Studio`: 4.2.3

Now you should be able to build your apks properly.

Comment: Thank You. Still have a problem after those changes

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a same problem and it was solved by switching off the offline mode, you can try it out

Comment: Thank You. Please, how can I do it?

Comment: at the right side of android studio u can find the Gradle tab open that, there u can find the toggle offline mode button, else u can go to settings and search for offline mode there u can off the offline mode

Comment: I did'nt find Gradle tab on my Android Studio !!!!!!!!!!! 4.2.2.

Comment: u can search for **offline mode** in settings